# PHP5 don't work in browser but in Bash

Tags: php, linux

I try to save a text into a file with PHP. 
But this code works in bash

`sudo php5 send.php`

fine but when I try to create the File via Browser it does nothing.

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $file = '/absolute/path/to/file/text.txt';;
   file_put_contents($file,"Hello World");
?>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I dont get any errors

Comment: Does you setup show errors, or save them to an error log?

Comment: the webserver user likely doesn't have permissions to write to the file/folder. When run under the web server, it is being run as apache or httpd (assuming apache server). Within bash, it is being run as you which does have permission.

Comment: You may have different `php.ini` configs.

Comment: It doesn't shows error on web or bash

Comment: how can I change the permissions for Internet use

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the permissions to the folder and now it works fine:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/*`

I don't know if there are any safety problems but this Server is just in lan